# Why is infimum chosen to define value at risk as opposed to the minimum?

Tags: risk, value-at-risk

I believe that the VaR is defined as the infimum of the generalized inverse of the CDF of the loss function (something like that, please correct accordingly):

$$\text{VaR}(\alpha)=\inf\{x: F_L(x)\geq \alpha\}=F_L^{\leftarrow}(\alpha)$$

I understand that whenever there is a sudden jump in the CDF and a plateau, the value-at-risk will not budge, but why is it infimum and not minimum on a case like this:

[image]

I see that the $$\text{VaR}(\alpha_1)=\text{VaR}(\alpha_2),$$ but $$\text{VaR}(\alpha_0)\neq \text{VaR}(\alpha_1).$$

However, the minimum would work just as well as the infimum.

> Why wouldn't the definition work out if the value at risk was defined identically, except for $\min$ instead of $\inf$? As in

$$\text{VaR}(\alpha)=\min\{x: F_L(x)\geq \alpha\}=F_L^{\leftarrow}(\alpha)$$

> I guess my question is in which scenario will the minimum not coincide with the infimum, and why?

Is the infimum chosen to work around situations like this:

[image]

?

Comment: Wiki has the infimum on the pnl function, not on the loss function. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_at_risk

Comment: With respect to your 2nd question regarding inf vs. min, I think [this thread in the Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342749/what-is-the-difference-between-minimum-and-infimum) will be of use to you.

Comment: @KevinT I understand the difference between min and inf. The question is whether I can have an example with CDFs where the two would differ.

Comment: In practice, the PnL distribution is often not a smooth function, e.g. for credit risk; or it is derived from a simulation (e.g. market risk). You then have to truly *count* your $\alpha$-quantile  from the $N$ simulation results.